# Concrete5-8.x: Where do I add translation files for packages or blocks?

Tags: concrete5, concrete5-5.7, concrete5-8.x

If I create my own .mo files for packages or blocks, where do I add the .mo files? Do they go in `/application/languages/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/block_handle.mo`?

Answer (score 0):

For package translations you have to put the files into `<your_package>/languages/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo` (the file name has to be exactly as my example)

Application files are under:
`application/languages/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo`.
But there you can not add a block specific translation. In the application folder are the core translations. What you can do, is to use the c5 internal translation interface, which will create an additional file under `application/languages/site/en_GB.mo`. But to use this interface you have to create the site folder first. You can find the c5 internal tranlsation interface on `<example.com>/dashboard/system/multilingual/translate_interface`.

Comment: Re: package translations. if I want to use translations on packages that are not mine, then I don't think it's a good idea to directly add the messages.mo file to the core package directory. Instead, can I add my translations to `application/languages/site/en_GB.mo` or is there an override feature that I can use?

Comment: @user1448031 when you do your translation on the page under the path `<example.com>/dashboard/system/multilingual/translate_interface` then the file will be created for you and you do not have to worry about possible problems.

Answer (score 0):

Just run

```
PATH-TO-CONCRETE5-ROOT-FOLDER/concrete/bin/concrete5 c5:package-translate PACKAGE_HANDLE OPTIONS
```

For more, visit https://documentation.concrete5.org/developers/concepts/localization